# Can I set custom ports for a ingress-nginx-controller by terraform/helm?

Tags: nginx, terraform, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, amqp

I need to expose port 5672 on nginx-ingress-controller externally.
In other words I want have that configuration on nginx-ingress-controller svc for custom forwarding rule on LB.

```
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 31792
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: 32613
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  - name: rabbitmq
    nodePort: 31190
    port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: amqp
```

For install nginx-ingress I use terraform + helm.
Unfortunatelly there is no option to add additional port in vaules.yaml
At the moment only option is customize http/https port.
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/fcda809ab034fffd14d8ff9b39441b2d12da420e/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L478-L483

There is any trick to use terraform helm operator to add this custom config to nginx-ingress-controller svc?

```
  - name: rabbitmq
    nodePort: 31190
    port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: amqp
```

Comment: Normally an Ingress only handles HTTP(S) traffic, and the Ingress controller is a hidden implementation detail of this.  If you need to make your internal queueing system externally accessible, a separate LoadBalancer-type Service would be a common approach, and however you're deploying RabbitMQ may already have this option.